# Multiple Switch statement

Tags: php, if-statement, switch-statement, selectlist

I'm having four selectlists (in breezingforms), which are called "OplKeuzeD1", "OplKeuzeD2", "OplKeuzeD3", "OplKeuzeD4".

All selectlists has multiple option values, some have the same optionvalues.

The PHPcode I'm using now to check if a value is selected in one of the selectlists is:

```
if($value["OplKeuzeD1"] == "OPTION" || $value["OplKeuzeD2"] == "OPTION" || $value["OplKeuzeD3"] == "OPTION" || $value["OplKeuzeD4"] == "OPTION"){
 $option = "OPTION";
}

if($value["OplKeuzeD1"] == "OPTION2" || $value["OplKeuzeD2"] == "OPTION2" || $value["OplKeuzeD3"] == "OPTION2" || $value["OplKeuzeD4"] == "OPTION2"){
 $option = "OPTION2";
}
```

Is there a way to do this in a Switch case to have less code?

Thanks very much!

**I forgot to mention that only one select list is shown on the screen, based on the previous answers of the form.**

Comment: an `in_array` variant would also be okay

Comment: If one of your four selects is `OPTION2` then `$option` is always `OPTION2` you do realize that right?

Comment: I realize  that it's $option will always be  OPTION2 , yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$array = array($value["OplKeuzeD1"], $value["OplKeuzeD2"], $value["OplKeuzeD3"], $value["OplKeuzeD4"])
if(in_array('OPTION', $array)) 
{

}
```

Comment: I prefer this one over Hamids version. :)

Comment: I accepted it, it's easier to read, but if someone is willing to let me know how to even reduce this version with less code :) (because colleagues with no programming skills need to understand it too.. First I had 200 lines of code.. now I have only 73, so that is reduced a lot :) )

Answer (score 0):

A simple way:

```
if(in_array('OPTION', array($value["OplKeuzeD1"], $value["OplKeuzeD2"], $value["OplKeuzeD3"], $value["OplKeuzeD4"]))) {
 // ...
}
```